# FontAwesome icon with fabricJS

Tags: font-awesome, fabricjs

I am trying to use FontAwesome icon on FabricJs text object but can't get it to render the icon. It works with regular canvas on the same page.
My code:

```
       const text = new fabric.IText('\uf0c2',{
        left: this.centerX, //Take the block's position
        top: this.centerY,
        fill: 'white',
        originX: 'center', originY: 'center',
        fontSize:60,
        fontFamily:'FontAwesome',
        selectable: false
    });
```

The result is a white rectangle (should be a cloud icon).
Is there a way to use FontAwesome icons with fabricJS?

Comment: Your given code works perfectly. You may have some other issues.

Comment: Unfortunately not for me. I failed to mention that I am working with Angular 4. The code fails  on 2 angular projects.

Comment: Ensure the font is loaded, the code is ok.

Comment: Maybe the `fill: 'white'` is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you check your font awesome version ? is this icon available in that version you used ? please check it.

Comment: It is possible that, you used old version of font awesome and font that you used in IText is from letest version may cause issue of `not available` .